# What is the difference between direct updating react setter function on click and passing a function and then updating the state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I read somewhere hooks are asynchronous, that is causing the error below but can someone elaborate what is the error and how it is working after passing function and then updating state.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");
  const [laser, setLaser] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{state}</p>
      <p>{laser}</p>

      {/* Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. */}
      <button onClick={setLaser("laser activated")}>Activate Lasers</button>

      {/* correct  */}
      <button onClick={() => setState("clicked")}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The first is a function **call**, the other a function **definition**, which means you are caught in a loop of setting the state -> rerender due to state change -> setting the state, and so on without clicking at all, hence the `Too many re-renders...` error

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava why onClick() event is getting redundant in first case? It appears hook is ignoring the onclick and updating the state when component is mounted for first time, why is such so...

Comment: as for 【onClick={setLaser("laser activated")}】 onClick  will be valued as the result from “setLaser("laser activated")” ,【 setLaser("laser activated")】 will be evaled, so it will not be expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in Javascript usually when you do something like `myFunction()` you are calling that function immediately.

So if you would do something in your component like `console.log('hello world')`
You would be calling the console.log() every time the component renders.

You could avoid doing a call every render by simple wrapping your call in a function

```
const myConsoleLog = () => {
  console.log('Hello World');
}
```

In this case you are declaring a function, that when called, it will call your console.log().

Now let's do 2 + 2 and help you with your problem.

In your 1st button you are doing `onClick={setLaser("laser activated")}`. Basically you are calling `setLaser()` because of the () at the end. And because you are setting a state, react re-renders. Because react re-renders react will call the `setLaser()` again and so on and so forth.

Basically what you want to do is what you did in your second button (basically doing my 2nd scenario).
You are telling react that for the `onClick` event, you want to call a function, you don't want it to be called NOW!, you want to call it in the future. When? Well, when the user clicks. So what do you do? You pass in a function, in this case you are passing an arrow function, with 1 single instruction. Meaning: "Call this instruction when `onClick` fires"

You could do the same if you created an auxiliary function and passed it to `onClick` (instead of the inline arrow function)

```
const handleClick = () => {
   setState("clicked");
}

return(
  ...
  <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
)
```

Notice that when passing my handleClick function, I'm not adding the () to the end. Because I don't want to call it now.

Comment: i was aware that "when you do something like myFunction() you are calling that function immediately" but did not know that it will run even by ignoring any user dependent event. It is quite non intuitive in JS. Does this phenomena also happens in other programming languages, are you aware of that ?

Comment: But it is not ignoring the user event, it is setting the state multiple times (infinite number of times actually). If you instead put there a `console.log('I clicked')`. You will notice 2 things. 1st if you open your console without ever clicking the button. There will be a console.log there with the string 'I clicked' and 2nd if you then click the button, the console.log() will be called again, writing 'I clicked' again in the console. This phenomena only occurs because of setState().
Answering your question, this should only happen in functional languages like Javascript or Python.

Comment: " 1st if you open your console without ever clicking the button. There will be a console.log there with the string" ---> function invoked for first time without clicking and  by ignoring user dependent event, basically this i wanted to say and you said the same.

Comment: Javascript is working has intended, you are calling it even if you are passing it as a prop/param

Answer (score 0):

The error may occur due to following reasons :

1. You are directly updating or setting a state on page render or component render and this is not the way to use Hooks and event Handling. Instead of passing direct Component you may do like this :
   i.  <button onClick={()=> setLaser("laser activated")}>Activate Lasers
   ii.  Activate Lasers
   iii. Make laserActivation() function above the return keyword and setValues there.